# Segmentation Fault with structs c

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int money;
    char IBAN[50];
    char passoword[20];
    char email[30];
}account;

void create_account(account *ptr)
{
    printf("****Welcome to account resgister****\n");
    printf("Whats your name?: \n");
    scanf(" %49s",ptr->name);
    printf("Whats your email? : ");
    scanf(" %29s",ptr->email);
    printf("Type you password (from 4 to 20): ");
    scanf(" %19s",ptr->passoword);
}

int menu()
{
    char option = 0;
    while(option != '0' && option != '1' && option != '2')
    {
        printf("****MENU****\n");
        printf("0 - Exit\n");
        printf("1 - Create Account\n");
        printf("2 - Log in\n");
        printf("What you want to do: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &option);
    }
    return option;
}

int main (void)
{
    char option;
    account *ptr;

    while(option != '0')
    {
        option = menu();

        switch (option)
        {
        case '0':
            break;
        case '1':
            create_account(ptr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me when i choose my option 1 in my menu and then when im asked to write my name i write it and them gives me a segmentation fault in the line : scanf(" %49", ptr->name). I dont know why this is happening like before i had %50s and i look it up and changed to %49s to match my array size but the error persists. Thx

Comment: `account *ptr;` wants space --> `account *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);`. Don't forget to call `free(ptr);` at the very end.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer there? Why not `account ac;` and then call `create_account(&ac);`?

Comment: There are two compiler warnings for using uninitialised variables in `main()`, the worse of which is `create_account(ptr);`. **Always check the compiler warnings**. This is very likely to cause a segfault.

Comment: I am not seeing any problem like "Segmentation Fault", but there is one warning I am seeing in gcc :  `warning: 'ptr' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   52 |             create_account(ptr);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: @HimanshuDutta _I am not seeing any problem like "Segmentation Fault"_. Accessing the uninitialized vars `ptr` or `option` causes the segfault at runtime.

Comment: @Dimmezy Misleading to output "Type you password (from 4 to 20): " and then limit input to 19 with `scanf(" %19s",ptr->passoword);`.  Consider adjusting one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that seems to work fine:

```
int main (void)
{
    char option;
    account new_account;

    while(option != '0')
    {
        option = menu();

        switch (option)
        {
        case '0':
            break;
        case '1':
            create_account(&new_account);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Just change the variable account *ptr to account new_account and call create_account with the &new_account.

Comment: ok, *ptr is just one random address when it is not initialized. In my system, I was luck that the random address is aligned with `account` type. But it was causing issue in you system. Better not to pass a point which is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int money;
    char IBAN[50];  
    char password[20];
    char email[30];
} account;

void create_account(account *ptr)
{
    printf("****Welcome to account register****\n");
    printf("What's your name?: \n");
    scanf(" %49s", ptr->name);
    printf("What's your email?: "); 
    scanf(" %29s", ptr->email);
    printf("Type your password (4 to 20 chars): ");
    scanf(" %19s", ptr->password); 
}

int menu()
{
    char option = 0;
    while(option != '0' && option != '1' && option != '2') {
        printf("****MENU****\n");
        printf("0 - Exit\n");
        printf("1 - Create Account\n");
        printf("2 - Log in\n");
        printf("What you want to do: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &option);
    }
    return option;
}

int main(void)
{
    char option;
    account *ptr = malloc(sizeof(account));
    
    while(option != '0') {
        option = menu();

        switch(option) {
            case '0': 
                break;
            case '1':
                create_account(ptr);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

try this

Comment: You forget `stdlib.h`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When testing out your code, the first clue was in the compiler warning noting that your structure pointer may be uninitialized.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Struct/main.c|53|warning: ‘ptr’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|
```

Indeed, that is the base issue with the code as when I ran the code, I too got a segmentation fault.  Reviewing your code, within the account creation function, there is no allocation of memory for your structure.  With that in mind, following is the simplest bit of refactoring adding allocation of memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int money;
    char IBAN[50];
    char passoword[20];
    char email[30];
} account;

void create_account(account *ptr)
{
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(account));  /* Allocates a block of memory for the structure */

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc"); // Always check the result of malloc
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("****Welcome to account resgister****\n");
    printf("Whats your name?: \n");
    scanf(" %49s",ptr->name);
    printf("Whats your email? : ");
    scanf(" %29s",ptr->email);
    printf("Type you password (from 4 to 20): ");
    scanf(" %19s",ptr->passoword);
    free(ptr);
}
```

Also, to actually address the compiler warning, it is advisable to initialize the pointer in the main function.

```
    account *ptr = NULL;    /* Addresses the compiler warning   */
```

With that, running a test at the terminal did allow for the creation of an account.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Struct/bin/Release$ ./Struct 
****MENU****
0 - Exit
1 - Create Account
2 - Log in
What you want to do: 
1
****Welcome to account resgister****
Whats your name?: 
Craig
Whats your email? : c@email.com
Type you password (from 4 to 20): Hello
****MENU****
0 - Exit
1 - Create Account
2 - Log in
What you want to do: 
0
```

The main things to take away are to be cognizant of any compiler warnings you might receive as they often times point out possible undefined behavior, and also you might want to delve more into some "C" tutorial literature as it pertains to memory allocation of objects such as structures.

Comment: David, good advice on the NULL checking.

Comment: The pointer memory needs to be allocated *before* calling the function, because the pointer in `main()` remains useless.

Comment: Weather Vane - yes, I had done that in my refactoring to address the compiler warning, but forgot to add it in the code block.  Going to edit my answer now.

Comment: There are two warnings.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but the pointer `account *ptr;` *in the `main()` function* is where the allocation should occur, and then `free(ptr)` at the end of `main()`. Not in the function, unless you are going to `return` it or use a double `**` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to do one line change in your old code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int money;
    char IBAN[50];
    char passoword[20];
    char email[30];
}account;

void create_account(account *ptr)
{
    printf("****Welcome to account resgister****\n");
    printf("Whats your name?: \n");
    scanf(" %49s",ptr->name);
    printf("Whats your email? : ");
    scanf(" %29s",ptr->email);
    printf("Type you password (from 4 to 20): ");
    scanf(" %19s",ptr->passoword);
}

int menu()
{
    char option = 0;
    while(option != '0' && option != '1' && option != '2')
    {
        printf("****MENU****\n");
        printf("0 - Exit\n");
        printf("1 - Create Account\n");
        printf("2 - Log in\n");
        printf("What you want to do: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &option);
    }
    return option;
}

int main (void)
{
    char option;
    account new_acc;
    account *ptr = &new_acc;

    while(option != '0')
    {
        option = menu();

        switch (option)
        {
        case '0':
            break;
        case '1':
            create_account(ptr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the extra line:

account new_acc;
account *ptr = &new_acc;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `    account new_acc;
    account *ptr = &new_acc;` is the extra line.